# DriveInfo with iSCSI drives

Tags: c#, iscsi, driveinfo

I have been planning on writing some code that checks the free space on numerous disks attached to a server, which are mounted using iSCSI.

It's been warned that "polling for free space on a dead mount causes a very long timeout".

My question is basically this: Is this true when using the DiskInfo class, and is there a better alternative to determine the free space available on a disk mounted this way, at least "better" in that it doesn't hang for a long time and responds in a predictable manner?

Comment: It is an Internet protocol, of course it will cause delays.  Checking up front never makes any sense.  Another client will gobble up a gigabyte between the time you check and the time you use.  Don't waste the time to check "will it work".  Deal with failure after you tried to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as the delays are caused by Windows' IO subsystem. But you're free to use the `DiskInfo` class in a second thread - so your UI won't be blocked.